# Modifying existing Knockout.js computed observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have a scenario where it would be nice to be able to change the read method of a Knockout computed observable in order to change how it calculates the result. I tried straight up re-creating the computed, but unfortunately that made the field stop computing. I'm assuming that wholly replacing the computed observable broke something behind the scenes in the dependency logic. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a code issue, but haven't provided any code for someone to help.  If you can provide some code that reproduces the issue then someone will be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the "read" function of a computed observable. But you can have conditionals within the function and call another function:

```
self.xyz = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.someCondition() ? self.methodA() : self.methodB();
});
```

You could also have your computed call a method within your view-model, which you can redefine at any time. If you want to make sure that the computed is updated whenever you update the function, you should use an observable to store the function:

```
self.methodA = ko.observable(function () { /*initial calculation*/ });

self.xyz = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.methodA()();
});

// sometime later
self.methodA(function () { /*new calculation*/ });
```